# how to sum only the selected cells on google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sum

I've been trying to find out how to sum only the selected cells, lets say I have the following table:

| Sum result |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 500 |

now, when I select, let say cells 1, 3, 4, 5, I want the Sum Result give me the sum, in this case 9, or if I select cells 500 and 5, I want it to return 505. Is this possible?

I believe it is with app script, but to be honest, I have no idea how to do this, below is a spreadsheet for testing,

Thanks in advance!!

[Shared Sheet Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a2uArwoj6pUu-SwFbVR4Y58ZmgPUh6LRY9nfBNa1Qlk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

You can already do that.  If you select several cells using the Ctrl key you will see the sum in the lower right hand corner.

[image]

If you need to use the number in another calculations you can `onSelectionChange()` to sum the numbers collected on the sheet.  After defining your `onSelectionChange()` trigger you need to close and reopen your spreadsheet to get it to work.

[image]

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if( sheet.getName() === "Test") {
    if( e.range.getColumn() === 1 ) {  // Column A
      let row = e.range.getRow();
      let sum = 0;
      if( ( row > 0 ) && ( row < 11 ) ) {  // Row 1 to 10
        let selection = sheet.getSelection();
        let rangeList = selection.getActiveRangeList();
        rangeList.getRanges().forEach( range => {
            let value = range.getValue();
            if( !isNaN(Number(value)) ) sum = sum+value;
          }
        )
      }
      sheet.getRange("C1").setValue(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Sheet.getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSelection())
- [Selection.getActiveRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection#getActiveRangeList())

Comment: Sorry but that is not what I meant...

Comment: Then please explain how you want to do this, menu, button?

Comment: I want a cell to display the result, thanks in  advance

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it with a script this will do it and display it as a toast.

```
function sumselectedCells() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let sum = breakUpRangeList(ss,sh,sh.getActiveRangeList()).getRanges().reduce((a,r,i) => (a += r.getValue(),a),0);
  ss.toast(`sum: ${sum}`);
}
```

The below function breaks up ranges into single cell ranges.

```
function breakUpRangeList(ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0"), rgl) {
  let b = [];
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg => {
    rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
      let row = rg.getRow() + i;
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        let col = rg.getColumn() + j;
        b.push(sh.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation())
      })
    })
  })
  b = [...new Set(b)];//create an array with no duplicate elements
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));
  return sh.getRangeList(b);
}
```

- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Sheet.getActiveRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactiverangelist)

Comment: wow amazing bro, works like a charm, you are the best, thanks!!